# Libgdx internationalization error

Tags: internationalization, libgdx

I'm trying to develop a translator for my Libgdx game but when I use the function "get(String key)" function the app crashes.
Here's my Translator class which extends from I18NBundle:

```
public class Translator extends I18NBundle {

public Translator(String language, String location) {
    // Load the bundle file
    FileHandle fileHandle = Gdx.files.internal("i18n/MyBundle");

    // Create a locale based on the language
    Locale locale = new Locale(language.toLowerCase(), location.toUpperCase());

    // Create the internationalized bundle
    super.createBundle(fileHandle, locale);
}
```

}

To check if my translator object got the strings I did that for debug:

```
String string = this.game.translator.get("gameTitle");
Gdx.app.log(Configuration.TAG, string);
```

It shows a NullPointerException, but it was instantiated from the main class. What can it be?

[image]

Comment: You need to figure out exactly what is causing the NPE.  Separate dereferences (e.g., the this.game, vs game.translator, vs. translator.get) so the line number will tell you more.  If you're still having problems post the stack trace.

Comment: The Translator class are inside my Game class, so I access it by this.game.translator. It's doesn't show a error when load the bundle, just when I use the method get().

Comment: Please include the stacktrace from the log.